# Unable to get all ajax parameters in MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, model-view-controller

When creating an ajax call to controller getting 2nd parameter only.

Ajax:

```
return $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "/myform/AddEmployee",
          data: '{ "EmpDetail":' + JSON.stringify(employee) + ', "File_ID":' + File_ID + '}',
          //data: JSON.stringify(employee,File_ID),
          dataType: "json"
      })
```

Controller:-

```
public string AddEmployee(EmpDetail Emp, int? File_ID)
      {
       ....
}
```

Model:-

```
 public partial class EmpDetail
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime DOB { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime JoiningDate { get; set; }
        public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
        public int DesignationID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> FileId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> StateId { get; set; }
    }
```

I have also tried

```
data: JSON.stringify(employee,File_ID)
```

I know this is wrong, but here I'm getting the first parameter only.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the objects directly? Hacking together a JSON string is a very brittle approach, plus providing `EmpDetail` as a string could be problematic for the ModelBinder. `data: { EmpDetail: employee, File_ID: File_ID },`

Comment: i have tried this and also this data: { EmpDetail: JSON.stringify(employee), File_ID: File_ID },  but only getting 2nd parameter 1st one is blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 var empData= JSON.stringify({ EmpDetail: employee, File_ID: File_ID });
```

And ajax,

```
return $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "/myform/AddEmployee",
          data: empData,
          dataType: "json"
      })
```

Hope helps.

Comment: EmpDetails is blank here, only getting file_ID

Comment: @SunilChaudhry Your employee variable should have same name as the parameter what you are expecting in controller.

Comment: I am passing the same name

Comment: @SunilChaudhry In Controller; the parameter name "Emp", in data "employee".

Answer (score 0):

You can send an javascript object instead of a string

```
return $http({
              method: "post",
              url: "/myform/AddEmployee",
              data: { EmpDetail: employee, File_ID: File_ID },              
              dataType: "json"
          })
```

Comment: EmpDetails is blank, only getting file_ID

Comment: Can you update your code and put the value of the employee variable

Comment: EmpDetails  or EmpDetail? the variable you sent is EmpDetail